# Clear garbage memory of other software in c#

Tags: c#, ram

this is a strange question.
In my work I use a software (that NO one can modify or take vision of source code), this software, unfortunately, is very bad. It uses, when launched, about 1 gb RAM, but running and being used, it accumulates data in ram and after few hours it occupies over 4gb of ram, and can accumulates more and more if not stopped. Since not all pc of my company can handle this, they crash. Is there a way to clear data unused in ram from other software programming in c#?
I just need an hint, i program in c#.
I'm sorry for my English, and if this question is somehow wrong.
Thanks for time.

Edit: I will add some information about this software understand better what I can do, and what I cant't.
Since i would not gain anything hacking this software, but I would have a better life (and not only me but my co-workers and employees too), i don't see any issue in hacking this software. (well, my chief has no problems, and his chief too).
I will try the Arunasr hint, I program in c# and know this function. I will only have to decompile it. 
I have to delete this question? 
Thanks for all replies and all help you gave to me.

Comment: Why is your application allocating so much memory?  Is it really necessary?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can't release memory that you don't own but if you could and did I'm pretty sure the rougue program will crash more often and then they won't blame the original developers but your attempt to solve it. Not a wise plan...  you could try to hookup a debugger to pinpoint the problem but more than that...

Comment: Are you asking how to fix memory leaks in an application for which you have no access or API? I don't think there's going to be a way to modify the internal state of that application.

The issue seems, to me, to be that you consider the memory leak to be "unused RAM," but if that were the case, the GC would've just reclaimed it in the first place. The RAM in question is more misused than unused, and that's not really the kind of distinction you can easily force on a closed application.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all for reply, i'm interested in @rene hint: "hookup a debugger", I will search information about this and will try somehow to find the problem, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such way, outside of killing and restarting that task. If it is a Windows Service, you can use Powershell, command line utility SC.exe, or this c# code:

```
public static void RestartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
  ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
  try
  {
    int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

    service.Stop();
    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);

    // count the rest of the timeout
    int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
    timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds - (millisec2-millisec1));

    service.Start();
    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
  }
  catch
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Reference: http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/

Answer (score 2):

.NET runtime garbage collector tends to be lazy and only collects when free memory is about to run out. You can force garbage collection with `GC.Collect()`, but mind the performance: it is expensive if you do it frequently.

If the library really accumulates data (i.e. data remains references and GC cannot touch it), there is little you can do other than hack up the library, figure out what eats up the memory and release the unnecessary objects. It is not difficult to decompile the .NET bytecode. In the extreme, you can modify the assembly bytecode using reflection after it has been loaded. I would not recommend it unless you are desperate.

You can use GC to track real memory usage stats.

Comment: @rene I noticed. He does have the assembly, of course, and it can be decompiled into C#. This is hacking and should not be attempted unless really desperate.

Comment: @arunasr "that NO one can modify or take vision of source code" seems to more suggest licensing issues than an inability or lack of knowledge in regards to decompiling the executable. Though I'm sure that if the license prohibits decompiling it'd probably prohibit anything that modified its behavior.

Comment: @rene My mistake, I misread the question.

Comment: I said no one can modify, because source code is not accessible, some one says it has been deleted, some one says the programmer is a bad person and says it has not, the software is totally owned by my society, so there is no legal issue. And yes, we are desperate!